# generate incremental mac address list in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to generate an incremental list of mac address, using PowerShell.

In a bash environment, I use printf:

```
mac=100
while [ $mac -lt 150 ]; do
printf %0.12X "$mac";
echo ""
let mac++;
done
```

Output sample:

```
000000000064
000000000065
000000000066
000000000067
000000000068
000000000069
00000000006A
00000000006B
```

I don't know how to approach this problem using Powershell.

What is the best way to get this result?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you need this. MAC contains vendor id that are registered, so be carefull not to collide. Your sample more or less directly translates to:

```
$mac=100
while ($mac -lt 150) {
    '{0:X12}' -f $mac
    $mac++
}

000000000064
000000000065
000000000066
000000000067
000000000068
000000000069
00000000006A
...
```

Comment: I use it in totally closed virtualized environment so this is not a problem, and thank you, this is just what I need!